# Use of ! (or any logical operator) with %>% (magrittr) produces unexpected output

Tags: r, magrittr

I have run across a situation where `%>%` produces very surprising output when combined with `!`. Consider the following code:

```
x <- c(1:20)
y <- !is.na(x)

> y
 [1] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE 
     TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE

> sum(Y)
[1] 20
```

Ok, nothing surprising there. But if I try to shorten it using `%>%` weird stuff happens:

```
!is.na(x) %>% sum

[1] TRUE
```

`TRUE`?? Not what I expected - it should be `20`.

If I  remove the `!` it gives me `0` as expected:

```
> is.na(x) %>% sum
[1] 0
```

and if I add brackets it works:

```
> {!is.na(x)} %>% sum
[1] 20
```

and treating `!` as a function works:

```
> is.na(x) %>% `!` %>% sum
[1] 20
```

What is `!is.na(x) %>% sum` doing, and why does it return `TRUE` rather than `20`?

**EDIT:** The other logical operators produce similar behavior:

```
> T&T %>% sum()
[1] TRUE
> {T&T} %>% sum()
[1] 1

> T|T %>% sum()
[1] TRUE
> {T|T} %>% sum()
[1] 1
```

Comment: `is.na(x) %>% \`!\` %>% sum` or `Negate(is.na)(x) %>% sum`

Comment: Or in magrittr speak `is.na(x) %>% not %>% sum`

Comment: @RichardScriven my favorite magrittr speak is `is_weakly_greater_than` for `>=`

Comment: @rawr @RichardScriven Yes, but in any other case I know the left side of the `%>%` evaluates first. Why is that not happening now? Is there just a rule that logical operators always go last no matter what?

Comment: see `?Syntax` then

Comment: @rawr - that clarifies things a lot. Thanks.

Comment: @rawr - I thought that was a joke at first.

Comment: @RichardScriven I am not a jokster

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suspect that it's an order of operations issue:

```
!is.na(x) %>% sum
```

is evaluating to

```
!(is.na(x) %>% sum)
```

Which is equivalent to `TRUE`

Answer (score 4):

Although I accepted @C-Z_ 's answer I want to add another to provide context on this. Thanks to @rawr for directing me to `?Syntax`.

Basically `%>%` is considered to be an operator, like `%in%` and as such it has to obey the order of operations. On the `Syntax` help page this corresponds to the `%any%` operator (i.e. any infix operator), as users can define these at will. As it happens, this means that `%>%` fires before any logical operator and also before arithmetic operators (e.g. `*` and `\`). As a result, if you are naively, like I was, thinking that the left side of `%>%` will  complete before the next step in the chain, you can get some surprises. For example:

```
3+2 %>% '*'(4) %>% `/`(2)
```

Does not do `3+2=5, 5*4= 20, 20/2=10`

instead it does `2*4/2=4, 4+3=7`, because the `%>%`  has precedence over `+`.

If you use the functions in the `magrittr` package such as:

```
add(3,2) %>% multiply_by(4) %>% divide_by(2)
```

You get `10` as expected. Placing brackets around the `3+2` will also get you `10`.

In my original examples, the logical operators, such as `!` have a lower precedence than `%>%`, so  they act last, after the sum has competed.

Moral of the story: Be careful mixing `%>%` with other operators.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the "not" alias from the magrittr package:

```
> is.na(1:20) %>% not %>% sum
```

[1] 20